# Как получить Thumbnail jpeg изображения расположеного на карте памяти?

Tags: android, java

Вопрос следующий: "Как получить Thumbnail jpeg изображения расположеного на карте памяти?" Мне необходимо получать уменьшеную копию больших изображений, так как при загрузке больших получаю OutOfMemoryException. Уже смотрел исходники галереи андроида, почитал, что написано, понял, но разобраться не смог как это сделать правильно)
Может кто-то решал подобную проблему? Расскажите как вы это делали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to Display Thumbnails of Images Stored in the SD Card](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-display-thumbnails-of-images.html)

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло

Comment: первая ссылка в гугле